# checking Array List content equals with List contents

Tags: java

i have two objects one is list(having variables a = 10,b=array,c=object) and another one is set (having variables a = 10,b=array,c=object) , i want to check whether content of List and set are equals or not ? Kindly let me know how to check this. Thanks in advance :)

Comment: tried equals , contains and overriding equals() , noting works , still trying.

Comment: you can never make a list and Set equal. You either have to compare each elements and conclude that they are equal or you have to first convert your list to Set and compare a Set with Set.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, compare the sizes, then iterate the list and check for presence in the set.

```
boolean compare( List<?> list, Set<?> set ){
    if( list.size() != set.size() ){
        System.out.println( "different sizes" );
        return false;
    for( Object obj: list ){
        if( ! set.contains( obj ) ){
            System.out.println( obj + "not in set" );
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Arrays is peculiar. This returns false if there are two array objects (not the *same* array object) with identical elements in the list and the set, respectively. equals never returns true for two *different* array objects even if they contain equal elements.

Answer (score 1):

A `Set` can never be equal to a `List`. They are completely different things. But a `Set` can be of the same size and contain all of the same elements as a `List`:

```
set.size().equals(list.size()) && set.containsAll(list));
```